# How to use .reduce() group data?

Tags: javascript, object

Please take a look at sample data.
I want to recursively group by this one.

```
const array = [
    { Type: 3, platform: 3 },
    { Type: 2, platform: 3 },
    { Type: 3, platform: 1 },
    { Type: 3, platform: 1 }
]
```

I want to group by platform
like this Or better presentation :

```
{ 
  platform: 3,
  '3': 2,       // Type : Type's count 
  '2': 1.       // Type : Type's count 
},
{ 
  platform: 1,
  '3': 2,       // Type : Type's count 
}
```

Comment: output format is bit confusing. Will you please add how you got that output?

Comment: you mean const array？
I want to be able to use the "platform" to distinguish the count of types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, 
Not the exact same output but better presentation

```js
const array = [
    { Type: 3, platform: 3 },
    { Type: 3, platform: 1 },
    { Type: 3, platform: 1 },
    { Type: 3, platform: 3 },
    { Type: 2, platform: 3 }
]

const data = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const key = `platform-${item.platform}`;
  if(acc[key]) {
    if(Object.keys(acc[key])[0] == item.Type) {
     acc[key][item.Type] = {count: acc[key][item.Type].count + 1} 
   }else {
     acc[key][item.Type] = {count: 1}
   }
   } else {
  acc[key] = {};
  acc[key][item.Type] = {count: 1}
}
return acc;
}, {});

console.log(data);
```

FYI: For better code representation you can customise this code by using es6 e.g(Object.assign etc).

Comment: thank you,I think it makes me more convenient to use

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const array = [
    { Type: 3, platform: 3 },
    { Type: 2, platform: 3 },
    { Type: 3, platform: 1 },
    { Type: 3, platform: 1 }
]


const results = array.reduce((aggr,curr) => {
let platform = aggr.filter(i => i.platform === curr.platform);
if(platform.length < 1) {
platform = {platform: curr.platform, [curr.Type]:1}
aggr.push(platform)
}else {
 platform[0][curr.Type] = (platform[0][curr.Type]||0)+1
}

return aggr;

}, [])

console.log(results)
```